# Let $Tf(t)= \int_0^tf(s)ds$ find $\alpha$ such that $||T|| \leq \alpha$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> On the space of $L^2([0,1])$ consider the following operator; $$Tf(t)= \int_0^tf(s)ds$$
> Find $\alpha < 1$ such that $||T|| \leq \alpha$

I try to use Fubini's theorem to compute $||Tf(t)||$ but I not sure how work with the integration limits or how is the right way to mayorate these.
Any hint or help I will very grateful

Comment: $\alpha =1$ works! But I made a mistake and write $\alpha \leq 1$ but the problem require that $\alpha <1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{1}|\int_0^{t} f(s)ds|^{2}dt\leq \int_0^{1} \|f\|^{2}t dt=\frac 1  2 \|f\|^{2}$.  So we can take $\alpha=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: @geetha290km really thanks!! I only have one question why $\left|\int_0^t f(s)ds\right|^2\leq ||f||^2 t$ ?

Comment: By Holder's ineqiuliaty the left side does not exceed $(\int_0^{t} |f|^{2}))(\int_0^{t} 1)dt$